# What is postgres, psql?

Tags: postgresql

I am learning coding right now and came to the topic about SQL.

However, I do not understand what is the difference between Postgres, psql and PostgreSQL.   I wiki about them, but I couldnt understand.  Can anyone simply tell what are they?  Thanks.

Comment: This looks very basic, you should have typed this in google search engine

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL is the database. `psql` is the command to access PostgreSQL from terminal. "Postgres" is just shorthand.

Comment: `postgres` is also the name of the actual database server (spawned by  `postmaster`).